# css: set image-width inside of paragraph with specific width?

Tags: image, css

hey guys,
somehow i can't find the solution for my little problem.
i have a paragraph setting with a max-width of 630px. 
in some cases i have images within one of those paragraphs - and in this case i want the image to act normal -> without any max-width setting.

```
.post-body p {
    width:99%;
    max-width: 630px;
}
.post-body p img{
    max-width:100% !important;
}
```

is it even possible to have the image larger than the max-width setting that's set to it's parent? do i need to use javascript (jquery)?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're modifying the image width some other way, as long as you don't do anything to the image it will display at full size.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/WrfQQ/

I didn't bother declaring any CSS for the image, so it, by default, will show up at full size. (Please note, for the sake of testing I decreased the width of the p to 100px)

Comment: oh, thank you-so true. i had it set as object! weird. thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the problem is that you put a MAX-width to the img... you have to code the relative width... so:

```
.post-body p img{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
```

if you want it in jQuery the code is the below:

```
$('.post-body p img').width() == $('.post-body p').width();
```